# RStan - very low CPU utilization

Tags: r, cpu-usage, mcmc, stan, rstan

I'm using stan in R and trying to make it utilize the CPU power as much as possible, to boost the speed.
My code looks like:

```
library(rstan)

[some data]

fit <- stan(model_code = stancode, 
              data = list(some data),
              iter = 5000, warmup = 2500, chains = 2, cores = 10)
```

[But each chain (process) is using only 4% of the CPU.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmwDU.png)

and it doesn't appear to be using ten cores. My CPU is AMD Zyzen 3900x (12 cores-24 threads). The resource monitor looks like this.
[Only 4-5 CPUs are active at a time, while the others are idle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtraR.png)

I also tried

```
library(parallel)
options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())
Sys.setenv(LOCAL_CPPFLAGS = ‘-march=native’)
```

and left "cores" as the default, but it didn't work.
What can I do to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

R version: 3.6.3

Comment: I'm pretty sure a Markov chain can't be parallelized. Thus, one thread is used per chain.

Comment: CPU usage also depends heavily on chip memory. but there's a new interface --- cmdstanr --- to Stan that enables multiple threads per chain. RStan has not yet updated to the latest Stan that has this feature.

Comment: Here is the tutorial: https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/reduce_sum_tutorial.html